# How to use entry_points to discover plugin in python with bazel in development?

Tags: python, plugins, entry-point

There is a lib foo, it use entry_points to discover plugin.
There is a lib bar, it provides plugin for lib foo.
As entry_points is working with distribution tools like setuptools, I don't know how to use this mechanism to discover plugin in development, which means I don't want to pip install lib bar.
My build tool is bazel, so I want to define a py_lib foo and py_lib bar, and foo can use entry_point to find bar's plugin.

I tried to look into entrypoint's doc, and there is nothing about development, it seems it is only designed to use with distribution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.